# How to download file from server to client in django on button click using js or jquery

Tags: javascript, django

**Here in Html i send the test cases which i want to download and on click of download button i hit the tcgsave save method in views.py in than check the request is from the download button then execute it part**

**HTML**

```
{% for testcase in testcase_object_array %}

                <form action="/tcgsave/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}         
                <input type="checkbox" name="name_testcase" id="testcase_id" class ="multiValueChek" value="{{ testcase.id }}"/>{{ testcase.name }}<br />
        {% endfor %}



<button style="width:70px;" class="btn btn-primary" value=" Edit" id="editbtn_id" name="editbtn_id" type="submit"> Edit </button>
<button style="width:70px;" class="btn btn-primary" value="download_btn" id="download_btn" name="download_btn" type="submit" onClick="window.location.href='{{tar_file_path}}> Download </button>
</form>
```

**js**

```
$("#download_btn").click(function(){
       var cnt=0;
       var checkbox_value = "";
       $(":checkbox").each(function () {
          var ischecked = $(this).is(":checked");
          if (ischecked){
                checkbox_value += $(this).val();
                //alert(checkbox_value);
                $("#testid_checked").val(checkbox_value);
                cnt=cnt + 1 ;
          }
        });



        if(cnt==0){ 

        alert("Please select one Test case");
            return false;


        } 
            else
            {


            return true;
            }

});
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^tcgsave/', 'apps.tcg.views.tcgsave', name='tcgsave')
```

**In views i create file and move that file in .tar folder to download on server side by sending the path of the file in "tar_file_path" variable at client side i.e html page**
**views.py**

```
def tcgsave(request):
    if request.POST.get('download_btn'):
        with open(Folderpath+'/'+testcase_name+'.java',"w") as f:          
            f.write("package "+inputpackage+";")
            f.write("\n\n"+lines)
            f.write(testcaseSummary)
            f.write("\n @testsummary")
            f.write("\n <pre>"+testcaseSummary+"</pre> \n\n")

        os.chdir("/root/ivenv/test_case_tool/docs/")
        tar = tarfile.open(folderName+".tar", "w")
        tar.add(folderName,arcname=os.path.basename(folderName))
        tar_file_path = "/root/ivenv/test_case_tool/docs/"+folderName+".tar"

    return render_to_response('tcgform.html','tar_file_path':tar_file_path,'testcase_object_array':pass_testcase_object_array},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**It give me error when click on download button**

Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:/root/ivenv/test_case_tool/docs/newProjectFoldr.tar

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, Django doesn't know URL:/root/ivenv/test_case_tool/docs/newProjectFoldr.tar where it is. So you get a 404 error(NOT FOUND).

You could write a corresponding url in urls.py or put the file in STATIC_ROOT folder(see your settings.py, add `STATIC_ROOT = 'static'` and `STATIC_URL='/static/'` if without), Then you could visit.

put the file in appname/static/ folder, when `DEBUG=True` in settings.py, Django will find it automatically.

visit `{{ STATIC_URL }}/newProjectFoldr.tar` to download the file. 
when deploy, run `python manage.py collectstatic` to collect static files to `STATIC_ROOT` folder, when `DEBUG=False` django doesn't server static files, you can use Apache.